# fluent nhibernate could not resolve property when trying to access property with backing field

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a class like the following: (SpecialFoo Implement IFoo)

```
private SpecialFoo _foo { get; set; }
public virtual SpecialFoo SpecialFoo 
{
  get { return _foo; }
  protected internal set { _foo = value; }
}
public virtual IFoo Foo
{ 
  get { return _foo; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
References(x => x.SpecialFoo)
    .Column("Special_Foo_Id")
    .Not.Insert()
    .Not.Update();
```

But when I try to query against the interace it comes back with fluent nhibernate could not resolve property. If I change it to use the SpecialFoo it works.

```
//Doesn't Work
return (from s in _session.Linq<SpecialFoo>()
          where s.Foo.ID == id
          select s).ToList();

//Works
return (from s in _session.Linq<SpecialFoo>()
          where s.SpecialFoo.ID == id
          select s).ToList();
```

Can anyone offer clues as to how to fix this and why this is happening? I read a bunch of different questions on Stackoverflow that were related to this, but unfortunately none of the solutions provided seemed to be applicable to what my particular case was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it will attempt to set against the property, but since that's protected it wont have access to it.

You can update your mapping to specify a different access-or.

```
.Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
```

But in that case your property backing field should be the same as the property name, like:

```
private SpecialFoo _specialFoo { get; set; }
public virtual SpecialFoo SpecialFoo 
{
  get { return _specialFoo; }
  protected internal set { _specialFoo = value; }
}
```

Edit: In response to your question below.

You could either keep the backfield the same as the mapped property, in which case you would update Foo property to use _specialFoo backing field.

Or you could reveal the member. (this is untested as I've written it off the top of my head)

```
References(Reveal.Member<SpecialFoo>("_foo"));
```

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties

This means it will directly look for the backing field given the name you define, rather than inferring the name based on your property and naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to keep a single backing field? I want to have both the interface and the real object available, and I would like to have only a single backing field.

Comment: @Phill, thanks! Unfortunatelly, it is still not clear for me how to do `where s.Foo.ID == id` when `Foo` is a _readony_ property. In my case `SpecialFoo` is a protected `IList` collection and it is mapped alright with `HasMany`. But `Foo` isn't. `Foo` is a readonly _IEnumerable_ over this protected _IList_ `SpecialFoo`.

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov i don't understand your question. The answer above is only about mapping immutable objects. If you have an issue I recommend you create a new SO issue explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Phill, thanks, i've just created it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959903/linq-to-nhibernate-and-how-to-map-a-second-readonly-ienumerable-representaion-of)